# Sending raw SOAP XML directly to WCF service from C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I have a WCF service reference:

```
http://.../Service.svc(?WSDL)
```

and I have an XML file containing a compliant SOAP envelope

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <MyXML>
       ...
```

Now, I would like to send this raw data directly to the service (and receive the response) via some C# code without using a Visual Studio service reference.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: did you ever accomplish this? How?

Comment: Have not succeeded yet, I'm afraid

Comment: Did you eventually just give up on the idea? What were you trying to do? Why couldn't you use the Visual Studio Service Reference? It's rather a fundamental feature of the .NET framework, in some ways, so I don't understand why you didn't just use that feature. Additionally, you could've created a class using the wsdl tool from VS and then used the client class to connect. Curious if you're still working on this issue in any way, since it's open and others will eb reading it (notice the 1,023 views as of now)

Comment: @drachenstern, I am no longer working on this issue. It was an attempt to do the WCF message security manually.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use [UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k.aspx). You need to set the `Content-Type` and `SOAPAction` headers appropriately:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            // read the raw SOAP request message from a file
            var data = File.ReadAllText("request.xml");
            // the Content-Type needs to be set to XML
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
            // The SOAPAction header indicates which method you would like to invoke
            // and could be seen in the WSDL: <soap:operation soapAction="..." /> element
            client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://www.example.com/services/ISomeOperationContract/GetContract\"");
            var response = client.UploadString("http://example.com/service.svc", data);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note for others, the "Content-Type" may have to be set to  `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");` and the SOAP Request input file may require `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

Comment: Also a note for future visitors: I had to to set encoding to utf8 for it to work properly: `client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 5):

I just want to comment that Darin's response worked for me, except that I had to take out the extra quotes around the SOAPAction header value (substitute your uri, of course):

```
client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://www.example.com/services/ISomeOperationContract/GetContract");
```

Comment: I'll also add that it works for me on 99.99% of services.  Some few services _require_ the <?xml ...?> at the front even though the W3 site suggests it is optional in the HTTP+SOAP world.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the webclient class and posting your xml to the service.